# How to get current location of others in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I have a project in which I need to get location of other people those who are in my contact list in iOS (like Find My Friend). So is there any library or any procedure or anything to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of library not available at that time . but this functionality is possible with manually setup.

**See this steps:**

1. Get each friends current location information.
2. Store them in a db in a server.
3. Access them from my application through webservices.

**Reference**
Google Latitude was helping to track others and later was depreciated. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Latitude

Hope this is useful for you.